# preventDefault on text area not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

`preventDefault` works perfectly on Chrome textarea html element when I try to avoid breaking line when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed and calls JavaScript function.

But it just doesn't work on Firefox...  is there a alternative solution for that?

This is the code that works fine running from Chrome:

```
    $("#textAreaID").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            CallJavaScriptFunction();
        }
    });
```

Comment: so, what part of the code "don't work" coz we see no code here

Comment: My guess is you are binding the javascript event at the wrong time.  That said, no code = no answer.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: @Eli I will bookmark that if you don't mind :) very useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the event parameter as `e`, but calling `preventDefault()` on `event`. It may not be your only issue, but you need it to be `e.preventDefault()`; in order to do what you're trying.

Comment: This definitely fixes the issue in IE9 and FF

Comment: I did what you said and it worked fine, that's just funny why it works on chrome in the first place. tks

Comment: @Edwin Snts, It's because Google Chrome defines `event` automatically in every `EventListener`, which Firefox does not.